# Where does the weirdly shaped metal piece go inside of Shimano grip twist shifters?

Tags: shimano, grip-shifter

[image: i found an image finally]Im trying to fix a bicycle that i found in the garbage. Its pretty close to being intact however, i noticed the Shimano grip twist shifter for my RD wasn't clicking. I opened it up and upon inspection noticed the odd shaped metal piece was not inside it. I have a few spare ones for parts so I have that metal piece now but don't know exactly where it goes. I thought I had it correctly because it clicked through all of the gears but only one way. Once I reached the last of the 7 clicks (7 speed) it won't reverse and go opposite direction to its original start position. I can't find a diagram anywhere online to show me proper placement of this piece. Any advice?

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the piece, and the way you originally had it inserted?  An exact model number of your current shifter would help too.

Comment: It's not an answer, but I'd send a shimano gripshifter to the rubbish bin.  They're notoriously fragile and cheaply made.   A 7 speed thumb shifter would be better - you can sink a lot of time into these grip shifters.  I have.

Comment: I largely agree with @Criggie despite having one working consistently acceptably on the bike I keep here at work (the front twist shifter broke and is a an old gummed up thumb shifter that doesn't work very well, but the back is doing well).  They do have the advantage of being pretty simple, if you don't pay too much attention to the pretence of indexing and treat them more as friction shifters.

Comment: I've got another as well, on a bike I'm breaking for spares, so can strip one down for a look, but I'd need a picture to know what I'm looking for

Comment: The lack of return can be a separate (but possibly related) problem of the cable sticking somewhere.  When a grip shifter tries to return against a stuck cable, it pushes against the cable, which flexes and gets in the way.  The strange-shaped bit might be a cable guide to reduce this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On SRAM shifters, these springs are so commonly lost by customers that the springs are sold in multipacks of 5 or 10 springs. Because Shimano twist shifters are much less common that SRAM, I might guess that you are trying to use a SRAM spring in the wrong shifter. Because there is a length of grip attached to these shifters that goes bad after a number of years or after exposure to heat and sunlight, I recommend not replacing just the spring. Instead, replace the whole shifter if you are going to spend the money. The whole shifter with cable is around $10 before shipping. If you buy the grip type shifter from SRAM and if your rear derailleur is Shimano, make sure that the shifter says "Shimano compatible". SRAM also makes shifters that only work with their own derailleurs.

Comment: Very informative response! Thanks so much! I'm just a beginner on bicycle maintenance, repair, and rebuilding. I find all the little facts so interesting. Just like this about the SRAM springs being so common to lose that they were sold in bundles! Yea I will get new shifter